# Unable to send Url in a Form field

Tags: html, apache

I am facing a problem while submitting a simple HTML form. Here is the form:

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="dest.php">
 <input type="hidden" name="my_url" value="http://www.livrotek.com/book_image/thumb/12726851341.jpg" />
</form>
```

When I submit this form, I get an apache error:
You don't have permission to access dest.php on this server.

If I change the value of "my_url" field to any value other than a URL, then it works fine.

Comment: Sounds unusual. What happens in dest.php?

Comment: No matter what happens in dest.php, even I tried to empty the file dest.php but it still got same problem.

Comment: Look in your error log. I'm guessing you have some sort of security module which is being a bit paranoid.

Answer (score 0):

Try URL Encoding the value.. Could be security related:

http://www.webtoolkit.info/javascript-url-decode-encode.html

Comment: I already have applied the URL Encoding and URL decoding to make it work for now. But it should work without encoding, in fact, it was working fine without encoding few days back.