# php $_GET error

Tags: php

```
$url = $_GET['url'];
echo "$url";
```

and I request 
/test.php?url=ok

gives me ok as output..

but I use a url
test.php?url=http://google.com

gives me 403- Forbidden error..
I donno why it's not working ..

Please help me..

Comment: It works fine for me. Is this your entire script?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to send Url in a Form field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793592/unable-to-send-url-in-a-form-field)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is often caused by overcautious settings of [mod_security](http://www.modsecurity.org/), an Apache extension. You'll have to consult your provider. (But they usually disable this individually or relax the settings.)

Answer (score 1):

Since characters like : and / etc are special characters in URLs, you cannot use them as part of a query string like that. You need to encode what you are passing in as a URL - in php that is done by the [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) function, and will look like this:

test.php?url=http%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com

Comment: Improper escaping is unlikely to cause a 403.

Answer (score 0):

I added `SecFilterEngine Off` to .htaccess . and it solved the problem
it's basically mod_security .

Comment: na I'd say it would be fair to accept @mario's answer here - after all, he came up with the idea.

Comment: Thanks..I am new to this site..I am getting used :)